# Nginx & Dynamic banlist

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I have block list of IP addresses in a file. How can I make this file a ban list for Nginx? This ban list resets every 5 minutes, it's a dynamic list.

Comment: i would not suggest to reload nginx every 5 minutes, imho its a vad practice. if you really need such frequency i think only nginx plus will be a solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a script which converts the file into a list of `Deny X.X.X.X;`. Add `include` directive with this file into your `nginx` config. Run the script when the ban list is updated and reload `nginx`.

Alternatively, use a commercial solution [NGINX Plus Dynamic Denylisting of IP Addresses](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/denylisting-ip-addresses/)